# Trying to close menu by pressing outside of it

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I'm making a pocketbook in Unity. On the upper right side corner there's a menu button that I've coded to make a drop-down list of links appear that will bring you to different pages of the pocketbook. Right now the only way to make the list dissapear is to click on the menu button again, which is inconvenient. I want the user to be able disable the menu by tapping anywhere else on the screen (I've created an invisible button that covers the rest of the screen, only problem is I want it to be active only when the scroll menu is active) like a normal menu screen. This is the code I've created for it. Menu Button is the menu button, close button is a button I created that covers the rest of the screen, I'm struggling to make the button active only when the scroll menu is up otherwise it will stop the user from scrolling through the pages. Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MenuButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject scrollMenu;
    public Button menuButton, closeButton;
    public bool active = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Button btn = menuButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        closeButton.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void TaskOnClick ()
    {
        if (active == false)
        {
            scrollMenu.SetActive(true);
            active = true;
            closeButton.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        } else
        {
            scrollMenu.SetActive(false);
            active = false;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are searching for popup menu, try this one https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is.
1. Make a button part of your menu, it should cover the entire screen
2. it must visible/hide with your menu
3. it must be transparent.
4. on the button click event attach menu hide code.
I have done that and it's working perfectly.

see the image below[image]